# How to create a category loop on my blog (ACF Plugin)

Tags: categories, loop, advanced-custom-fields

I want to create a category loop on my blog site, i already created some categories and uploaded featured images for them, but what's the next step?

Thank you :)

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked through ACF's docs?  https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/

Comment: Research creating a child theme, and from there depending on your parent theme, you'll want to copy over and customize either `archive.php` or `category.php`.

Comment: i don't know where to start, i know how to get fields but a loop is a little bit complex

Comment: How do you intend to use ACF with the Categories taxonomy? If you want to loop over posts from a specific category [that's done with WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) & I'm not sure what ACF has to do with that.

Comment: i need the featured image - that's only with acf possible